# How to disable matrix Column sorting in rdlc?

Tags: c#, charts, rdlc, infragistics

I have entered data from January to December in order, but when displaying in matrix in rdlc it automatically sort alphabetically "eg.. April August ... September.."  How can I disable this sorting?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Column Groups`, right click that column group name and select `Group Properties`.

In the `Group Properties` window, go to the `Sorting` tab and delete the `Sort by` column.

Now it should work as you expected.